# Difference between 2 apache mod_rewrites

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I've found 2 different code snippets to force https on my website:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I'm sure that they both work (one's from Httpd Wiki and the other's from SSL shopper).  Would someone be able to explain the differences in how they perform the redirect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They just use different Apache variables to make up the URL for redirect.

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This first rule takes the filename if one is entered such as myfile.php and appends the redirect with it replacing `$1` in the redirect so that you get `https://somesite.com/myfile.php`

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The 2nd one using `%{HTTP_HOST}` will grab the information from the http headers instead to make up the URL used to redirect so entering the same url `http://somesite.com/myfile.php` will be redirected to `https://somesite.com/myfile.php`

It's just a matter of telling apache what to use for redirection. Either use the server internal name or use the one sent by the browser.

```
%{SERVER_NAME}
```

That is a server internal variable in apache and is defined in the server config.

```
%{HTTP_HOST}
```

This is the what is sent by the browser in the HTTP request headers. This is client side while the `SERVER_NAME` if from the server config.

```
%{REQUEST_URI}
```

`REQUEST_URI` is the path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This is a special Apache variable.

There a many ways that have been done to redirect to `https` and both should work. Your choice.